# How to use the distinct method and use the operator $and in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to get the length of this table when I use the distinct to CustomerId but I would like to get this data until a date knowing that I have a PaymentDate property at my table.

I tried something like

```
db.getCollection('PaymentByCreditCard')
    .find({
        $and: [
            {"PaymentDate": { $lte: ISODate("2022-10-03T03:00:00.000Z")}},
        ]
        })
    .distinct("CustomerId")
    .length
```

But not works and this error appears

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: db.getCollection(...).find(...).distinct is not a function :
```

Comment: Does [this example in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#specify-query-with-distinct) help answer your question?

Comment: Hi @user20042973 I saw this documentation but what I tried did not work.

Comment: Can you help explain/show what wasn't working when using the documented approach? @NeNaD gives an answer advising to use this same documented syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[distinct](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) accept query as a second argument, so you should try this:

```
db.getCollection('PaymentByCreditCard')
    .distinct("CustomerId", { "PaymentDate": { $lte: ISODate("2022-10-03T03:00:00.000Z")}})
```

Comment: Thank you I saw about this second parameter `query`, but I have a last doubt.
Could I put more data inside of this second parameter? Like I would like to get the data between the `PaymentDate` using the `$lte` and `$gte`.

Comment: Yes, just add it `$gte` too.